# Customizing or Catching SharePoint ribbon action "New Document" in document library

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I was wondering if it is possible to catch or customize the "New Document" action in the ribbon when you create a new document in a document library.

The reason is the following: I would like to fill in some data into the document (pragmatically through the properties) before it opens in Word. This way some default data is filled in for the user. What data is filled in depends on the Site name. This would represent a Project number, what would be used to get the specific data from a list or database.

I've come up with some other solutions that basically fill in the data, but at another point of the process of the document:

1. using a combination of a Workflow & filling in the data through InfoPath. This works for a library with only 1 content type (the default). Once we want to use multiple Content types it is nearly impossible to get the site name because InfoPath is not able to use the function SPContext.Current.Web.Title.
2. To solve the content type problem I used the Event Receiver "ItemAdding". This way the data is added when the document is being added. The disadvantage that this gives is that the data will only be visible in the document if the users opens it a second time, what isn't really user friendly.

So to optimize the user experiences and usability I would like to add the data before the document opens in word. But is it possible?

I'm using SharePoint 2010 Server, Office 2010 Professorial and Visual studio 2010 Ultimate.

Thanks in advance,
Oxillery